# Trying to search for a value of an array and change the value when found

Tags: arrays, c

I am just starting c programming language and am trying to create a tic tac toe game. I found a lot of information and tutorials on the internet which I have been following and modifying. At present I have the code from the tutorials to update the grid based on what square the user selects. But I want to change it to a loop instead. I can not get the loop to work however. What am I missing or doing wrong....or can it even be done this way.
This is the code I have:

```
        if(player % 2)
        {
            player = 1; 
        }
        else
        {
            player = 2;
        }
             

    printf("Please enter the number of the square to place your marker  ");
    

    printf("Player %d : ", player);
    scanf("%d", &move);

    if(player == 1)//get the right marker
    {
        marker = 'O';
    }
    else
    {
        marker = 'X';
    }
    
    
    if  (move == 1 && grid_sq[0] == '1')
    {
            grid_sq[0] = marker;
    }
        
    else if (move == 2 && grid_sq[1] == '2')
    {
        
            grid_sq[1] = marker;
    }
        
    else if (move == 3 && grid_sq[2] == '3')
    {
            grid_sq[2] = marker;
    }
        
    else if (move == 4 && grid_sq[3] == '4')
    {
            grid_sq[3] = marker;
    }
    else if (move == 5 && grid_sq[4] == '5')
    {
            grid_sq[4] = marker;
    }
    else if (move == 6 && grid_sq[5] == '6')
    {
            grid_sq[5] = marker;
    }
    else if (move == 7 && grid_sq[6] == '7')
    {
            grid_sq[6] = marker;
    }
        
    else if (move == 8 && grid_sq[7] == '8')
    {
            grid_sq[7] = marker;
    }
        
    else if (move == 9 && grid_sq[8] == '9')
    {
            grid_sq[8] = marker;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\t\t\tMove is not valid! Try again. ");
        getch();
    }
```

I want to turn it into a loop and the loop I have been trying is:

```
for (i=0; 1<9; i++)
{
    if(grid_sq[i]==move)
    {
        grid_sq[i]=marker
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `1<9` should be `i < 9`

Comment: You also need to convert between `char` and `int`. `if (grid_sq[i] - '0' == move)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `for` loop condition, `1<9` should be `i<9`.

But there's no need for all those `if` statements or a loop. You can just convert `move` into an array index.

```
if (move >= 1 && move <= 9) {
    if (grid_sq[move-1] == move + '0') {
        grid_sq[move-1] = marker;
    } else {
        printf("That square is already taken, try again\n");
        getch();
    }
} else {
    printf("Square must be between 1 and 9, try again\n");
    getch();
}
```